# Postgis, get the points that are x meters near another point, in meters

Tags: postgis, distance, query, spatial-query

I'm trying to find the points within a certain distance, in meters, from another point.

I'm using the function ST_Buffer, but I don't get how to express the distance in meters.

I'm trying with something like this:

```
select
1 as cartodb_id,
ST_Buffer(
  ST_Transform(
    ST_GeomFromText(
      POINT(-58.38145 -34.60368)'
      , 4326
    )
    , 3857
  )
  , 500
) as the_geom_webmercator
```

I have the coordinates from google maps (in wgs84, 4326)
then I transform them to webmercator (3857)
and then I pass 500 as parameter, and I get something that looks like the desired area, but after comparing it with what google maps says it falls short for a non neglectable distance.

Is this the right way to achieve it?

note: you can try the sql query in cartodb

--

From this question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/44481/19461 I came with the following code (I use SRID 31997 to calculate the buffer, and then go back to webmercator)

```
select
1 as cartodb_id,
ST_Transform(
  ST_Buffer(
    ST_Transform(
      ST_GeomFromText(
        'POINT(-58.427185 -34.624592)'
        , 4326
      )
      , 31997
    )
    , 2000
  ), 3857
) as the_geom_webmercator
```

Now if falls short for no more than 20 meters. I thought mercator (EPSG 3857) was in metric units.

Comment: Do you really want a buffer geometry or do you want to know which given points fall within a given distance?

Comment: Also, do you really need to transform points to webmercator (3857)?

Answer (score 8):

If you want to test whether some points (or shapes, etc) fall within a given distance of a given location, use the geographic version of `ST_DWithin()`.
From https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html:

```
boolean ST_DWithin
  (geography gg1, geography gg2, double precision distance_meters, boolean use_spheroid);
```

Thus,

```
SELECT
  ST_DWithin(
      ST_GeomFromText(
        'POINT(-58.7 -34.2)' -- given point
        , 4326
      )::geography
      , 
      ST_GeomFromText(
        'POINT(-59.1 -33.6)' -- another point
        , 4326
      )::geography
      , 20000 -- given distance (m)
      , true -- for greater accuracy (false for greater speed)
    )
```

returns `false`
but

```
SELECT
  ST_DWithin(
      ST_GeomFromText(
        'POINT(-58.7 -34.2)' -- given point
        , 4326
      )::geography
      , 
      ST_GeomFromText(
        'POINT(-59.1 -33.6)' -- another point
        , 4326
      )::geography
      , 80000 -- given distance (m)
      , true -- for greater accuracy (false for greater speed)
    )
```

returns `true`
(The second example has a longer test distance.)

Answer (score 2):

Best way is to use the geographic type.

[geography ST_Buffer(geography g1, float radius_of_buffer_in_meters);](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_Buffer.html)

```
SELECT
1 as cartodb_id,
ST_Transform(
  ST_Buffer(
      ST_GeomFromText(
        'POINT(-58.427185 -34.624592)'
        , 4326
      )::geography
    )
    , 2000
  ), 3857
) as the_geom_webmercator
```

By casting to geography the st_buffer will work on meters, as you can see on the signature of the function.

Comment: ST_Dwithin should be faster than ST_Buffer